# Find center and commutant of the group.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

We have $G = \{\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} |\ \alpha \neq 0\}$ in $GL_2(K)$ ($K$ - field)

I want to find its center and commutant.
$$
Z(G) = \{g \in G \ | \ \forall h \in G \ : \ gh = hg\}-center \\ [G, G] = <[g,h] \ | g, h \in G> - commutant
$$

I tried to do this kind of computations:
Let's see what we have when we multiply elements from group:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\alpha_1 & \alpha\beta_1+\beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}*
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\alpha_1 & \alpha_1\beta +\beta_1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
That gives us some equality for center. (i.e $(\alpha-1)\beta_1 - \beta(\alpha_1-1) = 0$). And I couldn't get any statements for $\alpha, \beta$ we needed that we need for beeng in center.
So what about commitant I tried to find normal subgroups in our group (cuz we know that commutant is normal subgroup of our group), but could't get any good things there.

Can someone help me with a solution of this problem?

Comment: You have the condition for the center already computed. So which $A\in G$ commute with **all** other elements from $G$? Chose specific values here, e.g., $\beta_1=0$.

Comment: If the condition holds for *all* $\alpha_1, \beta_1$, then in particular it holds for all $\alpha_1$ when $\beta_1 = 0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|K|>2$ the center is trivial and $[G,G]$, which is more commonly called the "derived group", is the subgroup with the upper left entry equal to $1$.  If $|K|=2$, the center is the whole group and the derived group is trivial.

There are two cases: $|K|>2$ and $|K|=2$.  We treat the more general case first.

From the formulas you derived when checking the center, you can see that if $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
is central, then for all $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ you need $\alpha\beta_1 +\beta = \alpha_1\beta + \beta_1$.  For this to hold when $beta_1=0$ for all values of $\alpha_1$ clearly requires $\beta=0$ as $|K|\ne 2$.  That leaves $\alpha\beta_1=\beta_1$, so $\alpha=1$.  This shows the center is trivial.

A general commutator is of the form:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha^{-1} & -\beta\alpha^{-1}\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma^{-1} & -\delta\gamma^{-1}\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & \delta\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Multiplying this out, we get $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \delta\gamma^{-1}+\beta\alpha^{-1}\gamma^{-1}-\delta\alpha^{-1}\gamma^{-1}-\beta\alpha^{-1}\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

If $char K \ne 2$, setting $\alpha=1$, $\gamma=-1$, $\beta=0$, and $\delta=\epsilon/2$, we get any matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \epsilon\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$, and these clearly form a subgroup, so that is the derived group.

If $char K = 2$, take $\alpha=\delta=1$, $\gamma\ne 1$, $\gamma\ne 0$ and $\beta=\frac{\epsilon\gamma}{1-\gamma}$ to get the same.  Note that we use $|K|>2$ to select a $\gamma\notin \{0,1\}$.

If $|K|=2$ then the group has order $2$.  All such groups are abelian, so in that case, the center is the whole group and the derived group is trivial.

Comment: What is $\epsilon / 2$ here?

Comment: Half of whatever you want in the upper right hand corner of a commutator.

Comment: But what is 'half' in context of custom a field?

Comment: When the characteristic is not $2$, i.e., when $1+1\ne 0$, it's $(1+1)^{-1}$.  When the characteristic is $2$, I used a different approach.